# Cannot properly update total value in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm writing simple shopping cart system without redux.

**Expected behavior**: update the total amount when changing the number of products

**Problem**:

1. after first rendering total amount is `0`
2. after removing item total amount doesn't change

**I need:** elegant solution. Not a hardcode.

```js
const products = [
  {
   id: "1",
    title: "item 1",
    price: "2450",
    left: "14",
    quantity: "1"
  },
  {
   id: "2",
    title: "item 2",
    price: "2450",
    left: "178",
    quantity: "1"
  },
  {
   id: "3",
    title: "item 3",
    price: "2450",
    left: "1",
    quantity: "1"
  },
  {
   id: "4",
    title: "item 4",
    price: "2450",
    left: "12",
    quantity: "1"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      products: this.props.products,
      cart: this.props.products,
      totalAmount: 0
    };
    
    this.handleRemoveProduct = this.handleRemoveProduct.bind( this );
    this.handleChangeQuantity = this.handleChangeQuantity.bind( this );
    this.sumTotalAmount = this.sumTotalAmount.bind( this );
  }
  
  
  handleRemoveProduct( id ) {
    let cart = this.state.cart;
    cart = cart.filter( ( product ) => {
     return product.id != id;
    } );
    
    this.setState( {
     cart
    } );
    
    this.sumTotalAmount();
  }
  
  handleChangeQuantity( e, id ) {
    let cart = this.state.cart;
    cart = cart.map( ( product ) => {
     if (product.id == id ) {
       product.quantity = e.target.value;
      }
     
     return product;
    } );
    
    this.setState( {
     cart
    } );
    this.sumTotalAmount();
  }
  
  sumTotalAmount() {
   let cart = this.state.cart;
    let totalAmount = cart.map( ( product ) => {
     return Number(product.quantity) * Number(product.price);
    } ).reduce( ( total, current ) => total += current );
    
    this.setState( {
     totalAmount
    } );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="cart">
          {
            this.state.cart.map( ( item, index ) => {
              return(
                <Product key={index} item={item}
                handleRemoveProduct={this.handleRemoveProduct}
                handleChangeQuantity={this.handleChangeQuantity}
                />
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
        <div className="cart__total">     
          Total amount - {this.state.totalAmount}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Product = ( props ) => (
  <div className="cart__product">
    {props.item.title} <a href="#" onClick={() => props.handleRemoveProduct(props.item.id)}>Remove</a>
     <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max={props.item.left} value={props.item.quantity} onChange={(e) => props.handleChangeQuantity(e, props.item.id)}/>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App products = {products} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno added a chunk of code to help troubleshoot the problem, from:

```
  Total amount - {this.state.totalAmount}
```

To:

```
  Total amount - {this.state.cart.map( ( product ) => {
    return Number(product.quantity) * Number(product.price)
 }).reduce( ( total, current ) => total += current )}
```

The problem is twofold:

1) totalAmount is initialized to 0, and sumTotalAmount isn't called to update it until after you make a change to the cart.

2) totalAmount lags behind, especially on the last Remove, because each call to sumTotalAmount is relying on the state, which may not be up to date (the asynchronous part Bruno mentioned).

I would pass your (updated) cart to sumTotalAmount, and use its output to set totalAmount, both at construction and at changes:

```
constructor( props ) {
    super( props );

    this.handleRemoveProduct = this.handleRemoveProduct.bind( this );
    this.handleChangeQuantity = this.handleChangeQuantity.bind( this );
    this.sumTotalAmount = this.sumTotalAmount.bind( this );

    this.state = {
      products: this.props.products,
      cart: this.props.products,
      totalAmount: this.sumTotalAmount(this.props.products)
    };

}


handleRemoveProduct( id ) {
    let cart = this.state.cart;
    cart = cart.filter( ( product ) => {
        return product.id != id;
    } );

    this.setState( {
        cart: cart,
        totalAmount: this.sumTotalAmount(cart)
    } );

    //this.sumTotalAmount(cart);
}

// Make a similar change to handleChangeQuantity


sumTotalAmount(cart) {
    //let cart = this.state.cart;
    let totalAmount = cart.map( ( product ) => {
        return Number(product.quantity) * Number(product.price);
    } ).reduce( ( total, current ) => total += current );

    //this.setState( {
    //  totalAmount
    //} );
    return totalAmount;
}
```

Comment: I think we can also change total amount to use (prevState, props) => stateChange syntax, that is the recommended way to update state based on the state, so that react can assure that the state you are using to calculate is the newest.

Comment: After these changes I've got `setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.`. Initial value is not calculated also

Comment: Oh yes, you can't call setState yet in the constructor.  I'll tweak the answer to have sumTotalAmount return the total, which can then be used to set the state.

Comment: She wants the initial value to be different from the one that is declared on the constructor, so an additional render is necessary.

Comment: He already made the change, start total value with a sumTotalAmount call

Comment: But I still think that a (prevState,props) => stateChange solution is safer, but the solution above works nice

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the problem is that you call the sum method right after setState and setState is asynchronous, so when the sum is executed, the state hasn't changed,  setState receives a second parameter, a callback to be executed after the state is updated, see the doc below https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Making sumTotalAmount work based on prevState solves the problem

```
 sumTotalAmount() {   
        this.setState( (prevState, props) => { return { totalAmount : prevState.cart.map(( product ) => {
            return Number(product.quantity) * Number(product.price);
        } ).reduce( ( total, current ) => total += current )}
      })
  }
```

```js
const products = [
  {
   id: "1",
    title: "item 1",
    price: "2450",
    left: "14",
    quantity: "1"
  },
  {
   id: "2",
    title: "item 2",
    price: "2450",
    left: "178",
    quantity: "1"
  },
  {
   id: "3",
    title: "item 3",
    price: "2450",
    left: "1",
    quantity: "1"
  },
  {
   id: "4",
    title: "item 4",
    price: "2450",
    left: "12",
    quantity: "1"
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      products: this.props.products,
      cart: this.props.products,
      totalAmount: 0
    };
    
    this.handleRemoveProduct = this.handleRemoveProduct.bind( this );
    this.handleChangeQuantity = this.handleChangeQuantity.bind( this );
    this.sumTotalAmount = this.sumTotalAmount.bind( this );
  }
  
  
  handleRemoveProduct( id ) {
    let cart = this.state.cart;
    cart = cart.filter( ( product ) => {
     return product.id != id;
    } );
    
    this.setState( {
     cart
    } );
    
    this.sumTotalAmount();
  }
  
  handleChangeQuantity( e, id ) {
    let cart = this.state.cart;
    cart = cart.map( ( product ) => {
     if (product.id == id ) {
       product.quantity = e.target.value;
      }
     
     return product;
    } );
    
    this.setState( {
     cart
    } );
    this.sumTotalAmount();
  }
  
  sumTotalAmount() {
     
    this.setState( (prevState, props) => { return { totalAmount : prevState.cart.map(( product ) => {
     return Number(product.quantity) * Number(product.price);
    } ).reduce( ( total, current ) => total += current )}
  })
                  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="cart">
          {
            this.state.cart.map( ( item, index ) => {
              return(
                <Product key={index} item={item}
                handleRemoveProduct={this.handleRemoveProduct}
                handleChangeQuantity={this.handleChangeQuantity}
                />
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
        <div className="cart__total">     
          Total amount - {this.state.totalAmount}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Product = ( props ) => (
  <div className="cart__product">
    {props.item.title} <a href="#" onClick={() => props.handleRemoveProduct(props.item.id)}>Remove</a>
     <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max={props.item.left} value={props.item.quantity} onChange={(e) => props.handleChangeQuantity(e, props.item.id)}/>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App products = {products} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: If you show the code that is executed under totalAmount, the result is as expected,  so we can assume that totalAmount is not being called when you remove a product.

Comment: Thank you for solution but solution looks like a such a mess

Comment: Code works as expected but I don't see any differences

Comment: The explanation about setState being asynchronous, did you tried to use the callback ?

Comment: `Total amount - 0` still in first rendering

Comment: the problem is that you are starting your state with values that are inconsistent,

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: I will comment on Bryan answer

Answer (score 2):

The `setState` method is asynchronous, so `this.sumTotalAmount()` pretty much won't do anything.
You have at least three ways to fix your code:

- pass the sum function as the callback parameter to `setState` (and call `setState` in `componentDidMount`)

  ```
  this.setState({
      cart: newCart
  }, () => {
      this.sumTotalAmount();
  })
  ```
- make the sum function pure and call `setState` with the new cart state and the calculated sum (you are basically caching the sum *non-transparently* in state)

  ```
  this.setState({
      cart: newCart,
      sum: calculateSum(newCart),
  })
  ```
- make the sum function pure and use it only when you need the value (if you used memoization, in this case you would be caching the sum *transparently*)

  ```
  this.setState({
      cart: newCart,
  })

  // in render...
  <div className="cart__total">       
    Total amount - {calculateSum(this.state.cart)}
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1.`this.setState` is a asynchronous so when you are calling the function sumTotalAmount the state does not get update by then so you will be getting
sum of all items even though you removed one item.

2.Initially you are not calculating the sum so it is displaying sum as 0.
 So try calling that function `sumTotalAmount` in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. It least in my case (my solution)

Comment: i tried calling `sumTotalAmount`  in `componentDidMount` and its working see this: https://codesandbox.io/s/l4x945j647